# How to make the small header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning HTML as a beginner and I'm having difficulty making a small header like the one at the top of [this site](https://blazrobar.com/) or the one in the image below. Here's the HTML of what I've tried so far:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="dropdown_menu">
    <div class="small_header">
      <ul id="menu-small-menu" class="small_menu">
        <li id="menu-item-10429" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10429">12 Royal Street California USA</li>
        <li id="menu-item-6305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6305">001-122-134-555</li>
        <li id="menu-item-6211" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6211">contact@domain.com</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your CSS? This question is lacking information.

Comment: please share your CSS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO! As mentioned before, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can figure out how to help you. Also, you need point out exactly what it is you are having trouble with. If you just want to have a `.smallHeader` row the basic CSS could be:

```
.smallHeader {
    font-size: small; /* small compared to 'medium' (which is the default, avg. 16px) */
    line-height: 1.2; /* (without 'px') fairly common default. Will also center text vertically */
                      /* A higher value will increase top/bottom spacing of text, but */
                      /* instead you can also use 'padding' to create T/B spacing */
```

[MDN: font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size),
[MDN: line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height),
[MDN: padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Be aware, though, that with long text using `padding` for top/bottom spacing may have preference, because when lines wrap on smaller screens, each wrapped line will have the same `line-height` (usually not the desired effect) instead spacing *around* the block of text.

This is just one of many ways you can create a *small* header row....

A **snippet** using your code and some extra to show difference between `line-height` and `padding`. Run the snippet in 'Full page view' and resize the browser...

```css
ul,li {
   padding: 0; list-style-type: none /* override CSS defaults */
}
ul {
    margin: 0 /* ditto */
}

.smallHeader {
    font-size: small; /* small compared to 'medium' */
    line-height: 1.6; /* demo, default is approx. 1.2 */

    /* eye-candy */
    background-color: grey; color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
li.menu-item {
    display: inline; /* default is 'list-item'. This makes it go horizontal */

    /* eye-candy */
    padding: 0 1em; /* some L/R spacing between menu-items */
}

.bigHeader {
    font-size: x-large; /* extra large */
    padding: 1em 0; /* T/B padding instead of line-height */

/* eye-candy */
    background-color: black; color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

[class^="test"] { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) } /* classnames starting with "test" */

.test-lh { line-height: 1.5em }
.test-pd { padding: 1.5em }
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="smallHeader"> 
    <ul id="menu-small-menu" class="small_menu">
        <li id="menu-item-10429" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10429">12 Royal Street California USA</li>
        <li id="menu-item-6305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6305">001-122-134-555</li>
        <li id="menu-item-6211" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6211">contact@domain.com</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="bigHeader">extra large text</div>
</header>

<div class="test-lh">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et deleniti copiosae. Cu vel debet nobis, repudiare deseruisse reprehendunt usu ad. Ex elit idque nam. Omnis munere detraxit mei te, eu labore appareat verterem est. Mel ex oporteat consectetuer.
</div>
<div class="test-pd">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et deleniti copiosae. Cu vel debet nobis, repudiare deseruisse reprehendunt usu ad. Ex elit idque nam. Omnis munere detraxit mei te, eu labore appareat verterem est. Mel ex oporteat consectetuer.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this easily using **display:grid**. If you have an html file like this;

HTML

```
<header>
 <div class="smallHeader"> 
    <ul id="menu-small-menu" class="small_menu">
        <li id="menu-item-10429" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10429">12 Royal Street California USA</li>
        <li id="menu-item-6305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6305">001-122-134-555</li>
        <li id="menu-item-6211" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6211">contact@domain.com</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="bigHeader"></div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: auto;
}
```

This enables you to create a grid within your header, and makes sure each div insider your header takes one-row space! Then you can also modify the height,color .. of both of the divs inside your header.